# Behavior of points and compact subsets of Hausdorff spaces

Tags: general-topology, compactness, quotient-spaces, separation-axioms

It is quite straightforwad to see that many prpoperties are shared by points and compact subspaces of Hausdorff topologies, for example in terms of separation properties.

I was wondering if there is some more to this aspect and if maybe one could get some more insight by considering identifications of compact subsets to points (as throught quotients)

Comment: every point can also be treated as the compact set that contains this single point. So clearly they share so many properties.
I cannot think of a meaningful factorization of a Hausdorff space by a compact set. So I don't think this will lead to anything.

Comment: @NathanaelSkrepek Yes, in fact, I was wondering about the converse, mostly

Comment: I don't understand. what converse?

Comment: I don't know how well defined that sort of quotient would be. For example in $\mathbb R^n$ every pair of points is contained in a compact subset. As Nathanael said points in hausdorff spaces are compact, so every property that can be proved about compact sets also applies to points. I can think of a couple of properties that points have that compact sets don't, one being that points always have the homotopy type of a point while compact sets can have many different homotopy types.

Comment: @NathanaelSkrepek I mean, to what extent results about points may hold for generic compact subsets